# rust name fields in enum

Tags: rust, enums

is it possible to name or somehow else describe the fields of an `enum` in rust?
let's look at this code

```
enum Move {
    Capture(Piece, Piece, (i8, i8), (i8, i8)),
    ...
}
```

it might not be obvious what each of those values mean, in this case the first piece is my piece that captures the second piece and thereby moves from the first position (`(i8, i8)`) to the second.

Ideal would be something like this

```
enum Move {
    Capture(piece: Piece, captured: Piece, from: (i8, i8), to: (i8, i8)),
    ...
}
```

which sadly doesn't work.

Is there any way I can make my `enum` more descriptive (besides comments)?

Comment: Yes you can! Just use braces `{}` instead of parentheses.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum.html

Comment: Change `Capture(...)` to `Capture { ... }`

Comment: I have some helper functions like `getToPosition` that only cares about the to, is there an option to ignore all other fields in a match using the c-like enum structure?

Comment: use `..` to ignore all other fields: `Capture { to, .. }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use embedded structs like:

```rust
enum Move {
    Capture{piece: Piece, captured: Piece, from: (i8, i8), to: (i8, i8)},
    ...
}
```

Or even better, take them outside, where you can implement methods over them and then embedded it in you enum:

```rust
struct Capture{piece: Piece, captured: Piece, from: (i8, i8), to: (i8, i8)};

impl Capture {
    ...
}

enum Move {
    Capture(Capture),
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do you match on them and pull out the fields (based on your first code snippet)?

Comment: @AustinHeller just as normal pattern matching but with nested types.

Comment: I found that you have to name the properties you want to pull out during a match.
Example:
`match the_capture { Capture { piece: my_own_name_for_piece, ..} => { } }`